# Package amsmath Error: Multiple \labels

Tags: amsmath, ntheorem

I have seen that this subject was discussed a couple of times, but often the reason was like "oh, I used align* with \label". In my case it is a bit different, here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsthm]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:a}
a=b
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
a &=b  \label{eq:something_different}
\end{align}
\ref{eq:a} and \ref{eq:something_different}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, I get the error message "Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:a' will be lost. \end{align}". In fact label "eq:a" is not defined and is referenced as "??" in the text. It works when I change "align" to "equation" (and remove the ampersand) and it also works when I remove the " \label{eq:something_different).
Can anybody explain why this is the case and what I should do to avoid this error message?

Thank you very much.

Best regards,

Markus

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: And load it with the `amsmath` option.

Comment: you must use the amsmath option too: `\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks, amsthm]{ntheorem}`, see the documentation of ntheorem.

Comment: Not relevant, but `align` shouldn't be used with single-line equations.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I know that align shouldn't be used with single-line equations, I just wanted to strip down the example as far as possible

Answer (score 4):

From page 4 of the user guide of the `ntheorem` package:

[image]

Hence, replace

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsthm]{ntheorem}
```

with

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, amsthm]{ntheorem}
```

If, for some inscrutable reason, you do *not* wish to set the `amsmath` option while loading `ntheorem`, you  must load `ntheorem` before, not after, `amsmath`. Not the recommended route, though.

Comment: Thank you Mico, that does the trick. And sorry for not looking into the documentation thoroughly enough